# How to avoid select2 and ordinary input autocomplete dropdown conflict?

Tags: google-chrome, input, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I am using the `select2` plugin on my page.

When I double click any input which has the autocomplete attribute set to on and choose any option from the dropdown list, upon clicking any select2 the input`s dropdown shows again.

screenshot here http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=65140f9653ae3e082c3f20e326e44f51

This only happens in Chrome (probably only latest)

How do I avoid the show of the ordinary input`s dropdown?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=0fda28abbad9585ce9c3e426e60947a3

Comment: I expect to see only Select2 `s dropdown, but not an ordinary input field dropdown

Comment: i am having the same problem.it show remember password in select2 search box? Any Soloution